# Can we have custom permissions defined for the portal?

Tags: permissions, liferay, liferay-6, administration

**Environment**: Liferay 6.1 GA3 EE

Can we have custom permissions defined for the portal?

We can create custom permissions in our plugin portlet through creating an XML with `<portlet-resource>` tag and defining the `<action-key>` within it.

And when I go to define permissions for a Role in Control Panel my portlet appears in the section `Site Applications`, now what I want is to create custom permissions (not through EXT) in a portlet or hook that should have a separate category as `My Custom` and should have custom permissions like `<action-key>ACCESS_EMAIL</action-key>`, `<action-key>ACCESS_TOOLSET<\action-key>` etc.

In short my custom category should appear within section `Portal` as shown in the following figure while I define the permission for a custom Portal (regular) role:

[image: Portal Define Permissions]

I would like to use this permission not for a specific portlet but need to use it inside jsp-hooks or any other of my custom portlets. Just like we have `ADD_SITE`, `ADD_USER` etc permissions in `Portal` --> `General`, I want to have these permissions as generic.

***Edit***
To make the portlet appear in any of the section I created a simple custom-portlet, so the portlet appeared in the `Site Application` section and if I want I can make it appear in the `Control Panel` sections as well.

But now the problem is I don't have any view nor any implementation in this portlet so I make it hidden by updating the `liferay-display.xml` and putting it under `category.hidden`. This also hides it from the `Define Permission` drop-down.

And if I don't use the `lifeay-display.xml` liferay puts it under the `Undefined` category while accessing it from `+Add` menu in dockbar. :-(

Thank You

Comment: What would you like these custom keys to do? If you're developing a portlet, you can define these inside your portlet and it will show up in that drop down at the appropriate place.

Comment: @rp. I have updated my question as to how I want to use the permissions. Thanks

Comment: I see what you're trying to accomplish, but unfortunately I don't think that is an available feature.

Comment: @rp. Thanks for the help. My findings also show that it is not possible. :-( Can you suggest any other alternative apart from going the EXT way?

Comment: nice learning  But can you please check this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840274/custom-permission-to-custom-portlet-on-specific-user-in-liferay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how we achieved it:

1. Create a custom portlet with the permissions file for this portlet like `/resource-actions/custompermission.xml` to specify the different custom permissions we want. The full steps are identical to [this wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Permissioning+in+Plugin+Environment).
2. Make this portlet a hidden portlet so that it won't appear in the `Add` menu in dockbar, neither in Control-panel nor in the `Define Permissions` drop-down.
3. Now create a JSP hook (you can either create a separate plugin or include the hook in the custom-portlet defined in point no. 1) and modify the `/docroot/html/portlet/roles_admin/edit_role_permissions_navigation.jspf` to include our custom category:

   ```jsp
   <aui:form action="<%= currentURL %>" name="resourceSelection">
       <aui:fieldset>
           <aui:select changesContext="<%= true %>" name="add-permissions" onchange='<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() + "addPermissions(this);" %>'>
               <aui:option label="" />

               <%-- Our customization starts here  --%>

               <%--
                   We have added our very own option group but this is not required just the <aui:option> will do
               --%>
               <optgroup label="<liferay-ui:message key="custom" />">

               <%
               if (_isCustomPermissionsPortlet(CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS_PORTLET)) {

                   editPermissionsURL.setParameter("portletResource", CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS_PORTLET);
                   editPermissionsURL.setParameter("showModelResources", "0");
               %>

                   <%--
                       and here we add our own Permission category drop-down option
                   --%>

                   <aui:option label="custom-permissions"
                           selected="<%= _isCurrent(editPermissionsURL.toString(), portletResource, showModelResources) %>"
                           value="<%= editPermissionsURL.toString() %>" />

               <%
               }
               %>
               </optgroup>
               <%-- Our customization ends here --%>

           <c:choose>
               <c:when test="<%= role.getType() == RoleConstants.TYPE_SITE %>">
                   <optgroup label="<liferay-ui:message key="administration" />">

                   <% // Other liferay stuff continues ...
   ```

   and at the end of the JSP we have:

   ```jsp
   // ... other liferay stuff 

   private boolean _isOrganizationPortlet(String portletId) {
       return ArrayUtil.contains(_ORGANIZATION_PORTLETS, portletId);
   }

   private boolean _isPortalPortlet(String portletId) {
       return ArrayUtil.contains(_PORTAL_PORTLETS, portletId);
   }

   // Our customization starts here
   // portlet's ID
   public static final String CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS_PORTLET = "CustomPermissions_WAR_CustomPermissionsportlet";

   private static final String[] _CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS_PORTLET = {
       CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS_PORTLET,
   };

   private boolean _isCustomPermissionsPortlet(String portletId) {
       return ArrayUtil.contains(_CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS_PORTLET, portletId);
   }

   // Our customization ends here
   ```

   This is how it looks in the Control Panel:

   [image: Custom permissions in the Control Panel]

   We can move the permissions in the ***`Portal`*** section as well by moving our customized code to that place in the JSP.

   The advantage of having it above is that it will be displayed when we want to set Define Permissions for Site Role.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Hi Prakash K, would you please give me some sample code about this? I am confused about it. Thanks

Comment: @TomTang I have already included sample code in the answer. Let me know what you are confused about and we can take it up.

Comment: Thanks!, I already figure out it how to work follow your guide. Nice learning.